# How to configure prettier to disallow !important in (s)css files?

Tags: css, sass, prettier

I'm trying to configure our prettierrc.yaml to disallow the use of `!important` in (S)CSS files, but I can't seem to find any standard config or how to custom it.

Answer (score 0):

Prettier is a formatter, this is a job for a linter.

Consider something like [stylelint's](https://stylelint.io/) [declaration-no-important](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/declaration-no-important/) rule.